# How to get the time in am/pm format iphone NSDateFormatter?

Tags: iphone, ios, time, nsdateformatter

Am working in an iPhone app with using the NSDateFormatter. Am getting the time from the webservice like `"00:00:00", "16:00:00","15:30:00" and so on`. I need to convert these time to
if the time is `"00:00:00" to "12 AM"`, if the time is `"16:00:00" to "4 PM"`, if the time is "15:30:00" to "3.30 PM". I have used the below code to this but when i have pass `"16:00:00" the date returns null`.

```
 NSString *dats1 = @"16:00:00";
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter3 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 [dateFormatter3 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];  
 [dateFormatter3 setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"]; 
 NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter3 dateFromString:dats1];
 NSLog(@"date1 : %@", date1); **// Here returning (null)**
                
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
 NSLog(@"Current Date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date1]); **// Here also returning (null)**
 [formatter release];
```

When am passing "00:00:00" it is returning "12 AM" correctly. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If your time format is in `24hrs` please use `"HH:mm:ss"` format. Please test the code and let me know if it is working for you. I have tested and it is returning `"4 PM"`

```
NSString *dats1 = @"16:00:00";
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 [dateFormatter3 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];  
 [dateFormatter3 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"]; 
 NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter3 dateFromString:dats1];
 NSLog(@"date1 : %@", date1); **// Here returning (null)**

 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
 NSLog(@"Current Date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date1]); **// Here also returning (null)**
 [formatter release];
```

Thanks.

Comment: 12:12am here, but this returned 12:12pm .. Hmmm

Comment: it returns 16:00 in ios9

Comment: @PatelJigar add this [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]  initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];

Answer (score 23):

You can use the `.ShortStyle` which will adapt to the current locale:

```
let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
timeFormatter.dateStyle = .NoStyle
timeFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
timeFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

Which returns `17:12` or `5:12 PM` depending on the current device locale.

Comment: If you want to use `timeStyle` but still want to force 12h/24h format, there is a new proper way to do this, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75611188/3429396).

Answer (score 15):

Why are you again allocating the `NSDateFormatter` ?

you Just need to format it to `NSDate` and then again to `NSString`,

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dats1];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

    NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"%@",formattedDate);
```

Comment: Nice code... +1, but i think first `dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];` does not necessary.

Comment: It is necessary coz' he has the input hours format in HH format, i.e 24 hour format

Answer (score 14):

Try `HH:mm:ss` (notice the capitals in the hour format)

Answer (score 10):

Hope someone would be helpful who would like to get it in Swift

**Swift 5.1+**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
//if you want 12AM,5PM then use "hh mm a"
//if you want 00AM,17PM then use "HH mm a"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh mm a"
let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
print(stringDate)
```

Answer (score 8):

This Below code always keep in 12hour format:

```
NSLocale *12hourFomrat = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
df.locale = 12hourFomrat;
```

This always keep in 24 hour format

```
NSLocale *24hourFormat = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
df.locale = 24hourFormat
```

Answer (score 3):

your date format should be:

```
  [dateFormatter3 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
```

check the [Date Format Pattern Doku](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh mm a"
let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: While this seems like the right way to use this API, `DateFormatter` does NOT respect the `hourCycle` property (yet?) and just goes off the `Locale`'s region for whatever reason.**

If you want to format the time for displaying it to the user, then there is a new proper way to force the 12h/24h format using iOS 16's new [`Locale.Components`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/components) and the [`hourCycle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/components/3952289-hourcycle) property:

```swift
var components = Locale.Components(locale: .current)
components.hourCycle = use24h ? .zeroToTwentyThree : .oneToTwelve
let locale = Locale(components: components)

let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
timeFormatter.locale = locale
timeFormatter.dateStyle = .none
timeFormatter.timeStyle = .short
timeFormatter.stringFromDate(Date())
```

This will not override the user's other locale settings like language and region specific stuff etc.