# How we get date in 12 hour format

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want if user select 24 hour from setting on my string they get time in 12 hour format. I am using this code. It does not show the proper time.

```
timePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeTime;
[timePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
[timePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextFieldd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm:a"];
theTime = [dateFormat stringFromDate:timePicker.date];
NSLog(@"%@",theTime);

//    NSDateFormatter *DateFormatters=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
//    [DateFormatters setDateFormat:@"a"];

if (is24h ==YES) {
    NSArray *seprates=[theTime componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

    NSString *min = [seprates objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"%@",min);
    NSString  *hour=[seprates objectAtIndex:0];
    int hours=[hour intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d",hours);

    if (hours==12 &&[min isEqualToString:@"00"]) {

    }
    else
    {
        if (hours>=12) {
            hours=hours-12;
            period=@"PM";
        }
        else
        {
            if (hours==12) {
                hours=hours-11;
                period=@"PM";
            }
            else if (hours>12)
            {
                hours=hours-12;
                period=@"PM";
            }
            else
            {
                period=@"AM";
            }
       }
    }

    if (hours ==0) {
         theTime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"00:%@",min];
    }
    else
    {
         theTime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%@",hours,min];
    }
```

Comment: try this to get 12 hr formatted date `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];`

Comment: 14:13:pm it show time  but i m need in 2:13 pm

Comment: you see the answer set date formate "hh:mm a" @Varun Singhal

Comment: [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:a"];
    
    theTime = [dateFormat stringFromDate:timePicker.date];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",theTime);  show only 14:20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to force the date to be displayed in 12 hour format with AM/PM, set the locale to en_US.

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
  dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
  NSString *theTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];
  NSLog(@"%@",theTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
```

Set your full date with this formatter. I have just given hint.

Comment: are you sure using `hh` and not `HH`

Comment: [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:a"];
    
    theTime = [dateFormat stringFromDate:timePicker.date];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",theTime);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608133/how-to-get-the-time-in-am-pm-format-iphone-nsdateformatter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
 NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"23:50"];//suppose take time 23:50

 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
 NSString *DateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: @varun pass your datepicker.date in place of @"23:50"

Comment: i am getting output as    2015-07-09 15:50:35.159 Testing[1193:333724] dateString:11:50 PM    when i printing DateString.

Comment: just replace all you code after this     NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  by my code

Comment: Then your code should be               
timePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeTime;
[timePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
[timePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextFieldd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
 NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"23:50"];//suppose take time 23:50
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
 NSString *DateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];