# (Swift) Setting UIDatePicker View from User Input

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

First I display a UIDatePicker on the screen and allow the user to choose a date and time.  I save that value like this, which gets a date format that looks like this: 6/1/16, 1:47 PM

```
let time = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(datePicker.date, dateStyle: .ShortStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
```

Later on in the application, I want users to be able to edit their original date, so when a button is pressed, I would like the UIDatePicker to display the time that they had originally chosen.
I am using the following code to try to make that happen, although the app keeps getting a runtime error because the date is always nil.

```
let dateFromatter = NSDateFormatter()
let date = dateFromatter.dateFromString("6/1/16, 1:47 PM")
datePicker.setDate(date!, animated: true)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having an issue with the date format and not with the date picker.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dateFromatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFromatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yy, H:mm"
    if let date = dateFromatter.dateFromString("6/1/16, 1:47") {
      datePicker.setDate(date, animated: true)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes I realize that. I am not sure what the format would be for a shortstyle string

Comment: I am trying to say that the nil is not related to the `setDate`, but to the date formatter. You are not reading the date from the string.

Comment: The code is now working. I don't remember at the moment how to read the AM/PM symbol. Here is a discussion about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608133/how-to-get-the-time-in-am-pm-format-iphone-nsdateformatter

Answer (score 0):

For a short style string use below format:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yy, H:mm"
dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```